# Using Riemann definitions, Prove that $\int_{a}^{b} (c_1f_1+...c_nf_n) = c_1 \int_a^b f_1(x) dx + ...+ c_n\int_a^b f_n(x) dx$

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

> Prove (using Riemann's definitions) that if$ f_1,f_2,...,f_n$ are integrable on$[a,b]$ and $c_1,c_2,...c_n$ are constant then $c_1f_1+c_2f_2 + ...+c_nf_n $is integrable: $$\int_{a}^{b} (c_1f_1+c_2f_2 +...c_nf_n) = c_1 \int_a^b f_1(x) dx + c_2 \int_a^b f_2(x) dx +...+ c_n\int_a^b f_n(x) dx$$

Let's have as assumption that it has already been proven that:

- 1: "If $f$ and $g$ are integrable on $[a,b]$, then so is $f+g$"
- 2: "If $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ and $c$ is a constant then $cf$ is integrable  on $[a,b]$"

As we know that $f_1, f_2, ... f_n$ are integrable $\forall \epsilon >0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such  that
$$|\sigma_f- L_1 | <\epsilon$$
and
$$||P||<\delta$$
Where the limit L when $||P|| \rightarrow 0$ or $n \rightarrow \infty$
$$(b-a)\lim\limits_{ n  \rightarrow \infty}  \sum_{j=1}^{n} f_j(x) = L_1$$

We know as given that $cf$ is integrable, let's check if it is then so for $c_1f_1 + c_2f_2 + ... + c_nf_n$
The Rieman sum 
$$\sigma_{cf}= \sum_{j=1}^{n} c_jf_j(x) (x_j-x_{j-1})$$
$$\sigma_{cf}= c(b-a)  \sum_{j=1}^{n} f_j(x)$$
So the limit $L_2$
$$c(b-a)\lim\limits_{ n  \rightarrow \infty}  \sum_{j=1}^{n} f_j(x) = L_2$$

We know that $\sigma_{cf} - L_2 = c(\sigma_f - L_1)

$$\left|{\sigma_{cf} - L_2}\right| < \epsilon_2$$
$$\left|\frac{\sigma_{cf} - L_2}{c}\right| < \frac{\epsilon_2}{|c|}$$
$$\left|{\sigma_{c} - L_1}\right| < \frac{\epsilon_2}{|c|} = \epsilon_1$$

It follows that $c_1f_1 + c_2f_2+ ...+c_nf_n$ is integrable

I am not too certain if my "Riemann" argumentation is properly done here. any input or help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach A.**

With (1) and (2) you can use induction.

**Approach B.**

Without (1) and (2) consider for a subinterval $I$ of a partition,

$$\sup_{x,y \in I}\left|\sum_{j=1}^n c_j f_j(x) -  \sum_{j=1}^n c_j f_j(y)\right| \leqslant \sup_{x,y \in I}\sum_{j=1}^n |c_j| |f_j(x) - f_j(y)| \\ \leqslant \sum_{j=1}^n |c_j|(  \sup_{x,y \in I}|f_j(x) - f_j(y)| )$$

Recall that

$$U(P,f_j) - L(P,f_j) = \sum_{k=1}^n\sup_{x,y \in [x_{k-1},x_k]}|f_j(x) - f_j(y)| (x_k - x_{k-1}) $$

Now what can you say about $U(P, \sum_j c_jf) - L(P, \sum_j c_jf_j)$?

**Approach C.**

If you must use Riemann sums, note that

$$S(P, \sum_j c_j f_j) = \sum_{k=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n c_j f_j(\xi_k)(x_k - x_{k-1})= \sum_{j=1}^n c_j\sum_{k=1}^mf_j(\xi_k)(x_k - x_{k-1})\\ = \sum_{j=1}^n c_j S(P, f_j)$$

and

$$\left|S(P, \sum_jc_j f_j) - \sum_{j=1}^n c_j \int_a^b f_j\right| \leqslant  \sum_{j=1}^n |c_j| \,\left|\, S(P, f_j) - \int_a^b f_j\right| $$